# How to jump from a JFrame class after a specific time

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I would like to go to  jump from my progress bar (which is not an entirely progress just a gif) to another `JFrame` that would take me to the Login Frame after 5seconds but i don't want to use splash nor use buttons.

My `Loading` Frame source code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Loading");
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
    ImageIcon loading = new ImageIcon("loading.gif");
    frame.add(new JLabel("", loading, JLabel.CENTER));
    frame.setSize(400,400); // dimensions of the gif.(800x600)
    frame.setUndecorated(true); // removing the minimize and shit..
    frame.setResizable(false); 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

So basically after this code is executed for about 10 seconds it would jump to another class that contains another frame called login.java .

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Expanding 1, see also the [`SplashScreen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html). The log-in should most likely appear in a `JOptionPane` or a modal `JDialog`.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can use a `Swing Timer` to schedule an event.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

However, this is not the best solution!

> i don't want to use splash

Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel? Use Swing the way it was designed to be used.

A splash screen is designed for this purpose and will initially load faster.

The splash screen can be configured to automatically close after the specified time.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Create a Splash Screen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) for a working example.